# Flutter: Keyboard overflow with My Dialog

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'am trying to add TextField to a Dialog, but when the Keyboard appears, it gives an overflow.

My dialog Image

[image: dialog Image]

When the Keyboard shows up

[image: When the Keyboard shows up]

Here How a part my code looks Like:

```
AlertDialog(
    content: new ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      "How Would You Rate Our App?",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    )
```

Comment: Put the content into a `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: Not resolved:  AlertDialog(
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
          Text()]....

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can simply use [SingleChildScrollView](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html):

```
 AlertDialog(
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "How Would You Rate Our App?",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        ]
    )
    )
)
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to fix it.

Answer (score 27):

The problem is on the screen behind the Dialog. I faced the same problem but no one of the solutions above worked with my code so I used this code:

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
```

This line be under "return Scaffold"
I found this solution on this [page](https://medium.com/zipper-studios/the-keyboard-causes-the-bottom-overflowed-error-5da150a1c660)

Comment: There is no reference to `return Scaffold` in the question. Could you elaborate on the solution you found to include all required details?

Comment: This should be the best answer,

Comment: only solution that worked for me, thanks!

Comment: @68060 no tired it recently.
It was working a few months ago.

Comment: Worked for me thanks.

Comment: This solution pegs the problem and should be applied as the best answer.  In the original question it can be seen from the screenshot that the dialog has no overflow.  The overflow is behind the dialog.  Find the Scaffold behind the the dialog and apply this solution.

Comment: The referenced link gave me the solution. In my case, resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false did not fix it. But the Medium article also mentioned using SingleChildScrollView as did another solution. 
My case had a stack:
 body: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(alignment: Alignment.topCenter, child:SingleChildScrollView(child: resultsSection)),

Answer (score 2):

The "overflow stripes" alert is actually **on the screen behind the dialog**, therefore the dialog itself has no error.

Just try adding a `SingleChildScrollView()` wrapping around the child of the screen behind! 
(I had the same error and this worked for me)

Answer (score 2):

```
 AlertDialog(
        content: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "How Would You Rate Our App?",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        ]
    )
    )
)
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation for you answer and the code you posted for other people to better understand the issue and solution.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping this code around a dialog fixed this issue for me:

```
class _SystemPadding extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;

  _SystemPadding({Key key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    return new AnimatedContainer(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: mediaQuery.viewInsets.bottom),
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        child: child);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a flow as:

**Scaffold -> button click -> dialog box -> TextFormField -> Keyboard**

The issue was resolved by **adding the Dialog box to a SingleChildScrollView**.

That's it. Hope this helps someone.